# EXTJS/HTML--dynamically change color of html table cells

Tags: html, json, extjs, heatmap

I am creating a heatmap using an html table inside an XTemplate. The table columns and rows are dynamic and are driven from JSON data. JSON response will also include a property to indicate the color of the cell.

How do I take the color value and implement the UI changes accordingly?

```
this.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>" +
        "<tr>" +
            "<tpl for='.'>"+
                "<th style='color:white;'>{COLUMN_NAME}</th>" +
            "</tpl>" +
         "</tr>"+
         "<tr>" +
             "<tpl for='.'>"+
                 "<td align='center' style='color:white;'>{VALUE}</td>" +
             "</tpl>"+
         "</tr>"+
     "</table>"
    );
```

I'm not sure what kind of data this map will be showing so below is a stubbed json

JSON sample data:

```
  { "data":[{"COLUMN_NAME":"ColumnA", "VALUE":"HIGH", "COLOR":"Red"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"ColumnB", "VALUE":"LOW", "COLOR":"Green"}]}
```

TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will apply said color to the text. will this work?

```
<th style='color:{COLOR};'>{COLUMN_NAME}</th>
```

Comment: ah no crap, i feel stupid for asking this question now. of course it works, ty!